# Call onActivityResult for contact in OnCreate() Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-contacts

I got this code from another question but I don't know how to call this `onActivityResult()` class in my `onCreate()` activity to display the first contact from my phone. Also, what does "`if (requestCode == RQS_PICKCONTACT){`" and "`RQS_PICKCONTACT`" stand for? Could someone please clarify?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button buttonReadContact;
    TextView textPhone;

    final int RQS_PICKCONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        buttonReadContact = (Button)findViewById(R.id.readcontact);
        textPhone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.phone);

        buttonReadContact.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Start activity to get contact
                /*final Uri uriContact = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
                Intent intentPickContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, uriContact);
                startActivityForResult(intentPickContact, RQS_PICKCONTACT);
                */
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_PICKCONTACT); 
            }});

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if(requestCode == RQS_PICKCONTACT) {
                Uri returnUri = data.getData();
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);

                if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    int columnIndex_ID = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
                    String contactID = cursor.getString(columnIndex_ID);

                    int columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    String stringHasPhoneNumber = cursor.getString(columnIndex_HASPHONENUMBER);

                    if(stringHasPhoneNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                        Cursor cursorNum = getContentResolver().query(
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, 
                                null, 
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=" + contactID, 
                                null, 
                                null);

                        //Get the first phone number
                        if(cursorNum.moveToNext()){
                            int columnIndex_number = cursorNum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
                            String stringNumber = cursorNum.getString(columnIndex_number);
                            textPhone.setText("0"+stringNumber);
                        }

                    } else {
                        textPhone.setText("NO Phone Number");
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call startActivityForResult(intent,**requestCode**)

onActivityResult is called when user comes back to calling activity with

**requestCode** 
//You can start multiple activities by calling startActivityForResult so this            value is to differentiate between them

**resultCode**
//This value is set by the called activity to indicate whether the intended operation was a success or not.

**data**
//this is an object of type Intent which contains data returned by called activity.

in your code when this part is executed:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // BoD con't: CONTENT_TYPE instead of CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
                intent.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

                startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_PICKCONTACT);
```

New activity is started and when user comes back from that activity by selecting a contact onActivityResult is called

Answer (score -1):

onActivityResult is called after u startIntent or u select an contact. 
RQS_PICK_CONTACT u can change as u want. like 2 , 3,4 or another number.
it just identity for requestCode in onActivityResult so u can do as u need.